# Virtual Service Account without Network Access, like NT AUTHORITY\LocalService

Tags: windows, windows-services, windows-security, least-privilege

Background: I'm writing a service and want to give it as few privileges as necessary.

Virtual Accounts (sometimes "Virtual Service Accounts") are [sparsely documented](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) feature new to Windows 7/2008R2 that are automatically managed accounts for services that need minimal privileges but access the network with a computer identity in a domain environment.

My service doesn't need network access, so I'm using LocalService, but I don't like the fact that if I grant access to a file/etc I granting access to all services running as that account.

Is there a least privileged account I can use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change the account the service runs under; `LocalService` is fine.

Instead, configure the service to have a [non-zero SID type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685987(v=vs.85).aspx), i.e.,  specify either `SERVICE_SID_TYPE_UNRESTRICTED` or `SERVICE_SID_TYPE_RESTRICTED`.  You can do this using the [ChangeServiceConfig2()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681988(v=vs.85).aspx) function and the `SERVICE_CONFIG_SERVICE_SID_INFO` option.

You can then grant access to files and other protected resources using the service SID, whose name is `NT SERVICE\myservice`, rather than `LocalService`.  This will grant access to only your service.  (Well, and any other services sharing the same process, but most third-party services run in their own process.)

For least privilege, use `SERVICE_SID_TYPE_RESTRICTED`.  This means that the service can only access protected objects that explicitly grant access to either `Everyone`, the service SID, the logon session SID, or `WRITE_RESTRICTED`.  You should also use the `SERVICE_CONFIG_REQUIRED_PRIVILEGES_INFO` option to reduce the privileges granted to the service; many services do not need any privileges at all.  (In that case, you may find that you need to specify `SE_CHANGE_NOTIFY_NAME` rather than an empty list, though I might be misremembering.)

Comment: Is it possible to achieve this with the `sc` utility? At the moment I'm using a simple/understandable 3 line batch script to install and I'd prefer not to being P/Invoking around the place.

Comment: Sure.  `sc qsidtype` sets the SID type, and `sc qprivs` sets the required privileges.